# Excel - How to format the text of n-cells in a specific column

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have a file containg 15.000 of lines and I need help because editing all those lines by hand will take time.

For example, I have:

```
  |  | A              |B                |
  |  |----------------|-----------------|
  |  | Numbers        | Names           |
  |  |----------------|-----------------|
  |1.| ...            | PERSON-A        | 
  |2.|                | PERSON-B        |
  |3.|                | PERSON-C        |
  |4.|                | N-TH PERSON     |
  |5.|                | ...             |
  |6.|                | ...             |
```

I want the texts in the column B to be like:

```
  |  | A              |B                |
  |  |----------------|-----------------|
  |  | Numbers        | Names           |
  |  |----------------|-----------------|
  |1.| ...            | Person-A        | 
  |2.|                | Person-B        |
  |3.|                | Person-C        |
  |4.|                | N-th Person     |
  |5.|                | ...             |
  |6.|                | ...             |
```

In my file, I have names such as "BARACK O'BAMA SOMETHING ELSE", and I want to beautify that name as "Barack O'bama Something Else" all capilized.

Can some script do that for me? Any idea will be welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for `=PROPER()`: it'll capitalize the first letter after every non-letter character in the string. Make a third column to accomodate this:

```
  |  | A              |B                |C                |
  |  |----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
  |  | Numbers        | Names           | Processed Names |
  |  |----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
  |1.| ...            | Person-A        | =PROPER(B1)     |
  |2.|                | Person-B        | =PROPER(B2)     |
  |3.|                | Person-C        | =PROPER(B3)     |
  |4.|                | N-th Person     | =PROPER(B4)     |
  |5.|                | ...             | ...             |
  |6.|                | ...             | ...             |
```

**EDIT:** Included an illustration of the resulting table.

**EDIT 2:** For clarification: `=PROPER()` will capitalize any letter appearing after something that's not a letter. In the example above, that would mean a string like "O'BAMA" would be rendered as "O'Bama", not "O'bama".

Comment: Hm, and how would that be applied in the column? I have no idea how to apply it or where to.

Comment: Make a third column, C, that is equal to =PROPER(B). In that scenario, Range C1 would be `=PROPER(B1)`, and would appear as "Person-A". You can then (if you don't want Column B to be visible) either (a) hide Column B or (c) paste the contents of Column C onto Column B as values.

Comment: Great answer, even though, I have to put manually those `=PROPER(BX)`, but if there's a way to do something like `=PROPER(B1:BN)` or something similar to facilitate even more would be better.

Comment: You don't need manual input for all of the cells in Column C. Write `=PROPER(B1)` in cell C1; select cell B1, hit `Ctrl + Down Arrow` (going to the bottom end of the range, cell BX), move over to Column C (cell CX), then `Ctrl + Shift + Up Arrow` and `Ctrl + D`. That'll drag down the formula in the first cell to the last one, auto-filling the formulas as it goes down.